# Finding number of survived people in Titanic Dataset in Python

Tags: python, pandas

From the [Titanic Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data) from Kaggle, I'm trying to extract how many people survived and how many died from the `survived` column. To do this, I imported the `pandas` library and saved the dataset in the variable `dataframe` and used the following code:

```
dataframe['survived'].value_counts()
```

Which gave me the output as

```
0    809
1    500
Name: survived, dtype: int64
```

From this, how do I print just the number of people who survived? Like if I want the count of 1, I need the output as 500. Same thing for when I want just the count of 0.

I tried the following code only to get a `SyntaxError`

```
dataframe['survived'].value_counts().1
```

I'm new to pandas, so I'd really appreciate it if anyone could help me with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
dataframe['survived'].value_counts()[0]
```

or:

```
dataframe['survived'].value_counts().loc[0]
```

The `.column_name`/`.index_name` syntax is not recommended as it restricts the possibilities to column names that are valid python variables. Strings starting with a number are not valid python variable names.

Comment: Your `[0]` does not return the _first_ row but the count of `0` values. You look for `iloc[0]` or `loc[1]`.

Comment: @buhtz it is my understanding that this is what OP wants, the 0 values are "did not survive" and 1 "survived": "*I'm trying to extract how many people survived and how many died*"

Comment: It's exactly what I needed. I do need to extract the count for the 0 and 1 values, and this answers my question perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For your case, you can use `sum` instead of `value_counts` because you have a binary column: 1 for survived, 0 for died so the sum get you all survived people:

```
>>> dataframe['survived'].sum()
500
```

In case of your column is not binary, you can use:

```
# 1 stand for survived people here
>>> dataframe['survived'].eq(1).sum()
500
```

Comment: This just does summarize the integers in the column `survived`. Here you are lucky that `1` means _survived_. But what if the `938` is the code for _survived_?

Comment: I'm not lucky... I know the data, follow the link (first line of the table).

Comment: Logically the column is a categorical. The possible values could be `dead` or `alive` also. The opener used Titanic just as a very nice example to the very good question. Other readers and newbies need to understand and adapt the answers to their own data. In that case your answer does not help other people but mislead them.

Comment: Read my answer, not the just the code... All is explained. I wrote **because you have a binary column: 1 for survived...**. Do you think I'm unclear???

Comment: @Corralien I can very well understand what you mean. I never thought sum() could be used for this, and I never knew about eq() to date. Your answer just explained a lot more to me. And while like buhtz stated that it works only for binary, I use a lot of binary formatting already and this will definitely help :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more human like logic answer.

Ask the data frame for all observations (rows) with survivors in it.

```
# some datasets would use 'yes', 'si', 'alive', ..
alive = 1

# eq() means equal; like ==
survivors = dataframe[dataframe.survived.eq(alive)]
```

And then count the observations (rows).

```
print(len(survivors))
```

Comment: Why do you need indexing? `dataframe.survived.eq(alive).sum()`

Comment: You are very lucky `survived` is a valid python identifier!!! You should use `dataframe['survived']` instead...

Comment: This actually works if, like you said in a previous answer, that 'dead' and 'alive' replace 0 and 1 respectively. While the code is lengthy compared to @mozway, no doubt this one is really flexible. I'll use this for the sex category instead. Thank you for this!